# what is mean by machine level code and how to view it?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization, machine-code

We know machine level code are in form of 0,1 (binary). Now, in c programming using gcc for a program if cmd is -

`gcc -c ok.c`

where ok.c is a simple program to print "hi" in c.
Now, a file ok.o is created which is supposed to be machine level instructions.The content of ok.o file is something like-

```
^@^L^@UH��H�=^@^@^@^@�^@^@^@^@�^@^@^@^@�]�hi^@^@GCC: (Debian 9.3.0-10) 9.3.0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AzR^@^Ax^P^A^[^L^G^H�^A^@^@^\^@^@^@^\^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^X^@^@^@^@A^N^P�^BC
^FS^L^G^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^D^@��^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

and so on lots of character like this. what does this output mean and  if this is machine level instruction then why it is not in form of binary digit(0,1) i.e 1000110111111010101....(something like that) and also how can i see binary kind of code ? Please , also correct me if I am wrong somewhere.
Thanks

Comment: It is binary code. Notepad (or whatever you are using) is trying to decipher it as text. It probably assumes some encoding and tries to make symbols out of the binary code. And you get garbage basically.

Comment: The .o file isn't all machine code. There is other stuff in there. Overall, the file is in ELF format (at least on Linux). The machine code is not in its final form because absolute addresses will not have been resolved yet. Those are resolved when the .o file is linked into an executable.

Comment: What you need is a hex editor. I don't think it will give you much, but at least it makes it possible to view the raw data

Comment: `objdump -s ok.o` will show the contents of the file in a printable form in both hexadecimal and as characters for those bytes that are printable ASCII characters.

Comment: use objdump to see it decoded

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to produce an assembly file (ok.s):

```
gcc -S ok.c
```

The ok.s file be human readable text file (like your .c file). It will be a listing of the machine instructions. This is how a human 'views' the machine code.

For more information about what those instructions mean see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language

When you view your binary .o file you are viewing it as text (where 8 (or more)) binary bits will be forming a human viewable character depending on their value, which is why it looks like a bunch of random characters.

Comment: Assembly code is not machine code.  Machine code is a language consisting of binaries that can be directly executed by a computer while an assembly language is a low-level programming language that requires software called an assembler to convert it into machine code.  [more here...](https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-machine-code-and-assembly-language/)

Answer (score 2):

Given a simple C program like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  printf( "This is a test\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

if you want to look at actual *machine code* (not just the assembler, but the actual opcodes and operands), you have a couple of options:

- Build the file as normal:

  ```
  gcc -o simple -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror simple.c
  ```

  Then use the `objdump` command with the `-d` option (`objdump -d simple`), and you'll get a listing similar to this:

  ```
  00000000004004c7 <main>:
    4004c7:   55                      push   %rbp
    4004c8:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    4004cb:   bf 60 05 40 00          mov    $0x400560,%edi
    4004d0:   e8 1b ff ff ff          callq  4003f0 
    4004d5:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    4004da:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    4004db:   c3                      retq   
    4004dc:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
    ^         ^                       ^
    |         |                       |
    |         |                       +---- assembler
    |         +---------------------------- machine code
    +-------------------------------------- instruction address
  ```

  Build the file with the `-Wa,-aldh=listing-file` option to generate a listing of assembly and machine code:

  ```
  gcc -o simple -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wa,-aldh=simple.lst simple.c
  ```

  which will create a listing file similar to this:

  ```
  GAS LISTING /tmp/ccAMmy8W.s             page 1


     1                    .file   "simple.c"
     2                    .text
     3                    .section    .rodata
     4                .LC0:
     5 0000 54686973      .string "This is a test"
     5      20697320 
     5      61207465 
     5      737400
     6                    .text
     7                    .globl  main
     9                main:
    10                .LFB0:
    11                    .cfi_startproc
    12 0000 55            pushq   %rbp
    13                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    14                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    15 0001 4889E5        movq    %rsp, %rbp
    16                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    17 0004 BF000000      movl    $.LC0, %edi
    17      00
    18 0009 E8000000      call    puts
    18      00
    19 000e B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
    19      00
    20 0013 5D            popq    %rbp
    21                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    22 0014 C3            ret
    23                    .cfi_endproc
    24                .LFE0:
    26                    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)"
    27                    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    ^  ^    ^             ^
    |  |    |             |
    |  |    |             +---- assembler
    |  |    +------------------ machine code
    |  +----------------------- instruction offset
    +-------------------------- instruction number
  ```

  If you build with the `-g` option, you'll get the original source code interleaved with the generated output:

  ```
  GAS LISTING /tmp/ccJ7L1rJ.s          page 1


     1                    .file   "simple.c"
     2                    .text
     3                .Ltext0:
     4                    .section    .rodata
     5                .LC0:
     6 0000 54686973      .string "This is a test"
     6      20697320 
     6      61207465 
     6      737400
     7                    .text
     8                    .globl  main
    10                main:
    11                .LFB0:
    12                    .file 1 "simple.c"
     1:simple.c      **** #include <stdio.h>
     2:simple.c      **** 
     3:simple.c      **** int main( void )
     4:simple.c      **** {
    13                    .loc 1 4 0
    14                    .cfi_startproc
    15 0000 55            pushq   %rbp
    16                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    17                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    18 0001 4889E5        movq    %rsp, %rbp
    19                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
     5:simple.c      ****   printf( "This is a test\n" );
    20                    .loc 1 5 0
    21 0004 BF000000      movl    $.LC0, %edi
    21      00
    22 0009 E8000000      call    puts
    22      00
     6:simple.c      ****   return 0;
    23                    .loc 1 6 0
    24 000e B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
    24      00
     7:simple.c      **** }
    25                    .loc 1 7 0
    26 0013 5D            popq    %rbp
    27                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    28 0014 C3            ret
    29                    .cfi_endproc
    30                .LFE0:
    32                .Letext0:
    33                    .file 2 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/include/stddef.h"
    34                    .file 3 "/usr/include/bits/types.h"
    35                    .file 4 "/usr/include/libio.h"
    36                    .file 5 "/usr/include/stdio.h"
  ```